# Boost battery voltage by 150mV

Tags: voltage, batteries

When charging a battery I want it to turn off before it charges to the chargers full voltage.

Say the battery is 4.2v normally I want it to stop at 4.1 v say.

Forgetting the charger or whatever sensors or arduino codings and the like  can I make a circuit like a form of voltage doubler that just increases the read voltage by an exact amount .

As a diode will drop the voltage out is there a device or circuit that will increase it?

Comment: What charger are you using?

Comment: In theory, it's possible to make a power supply / current dumper that maintains 150 mV across its terminals regardless of current direction up to some maximum, either powered by an isolated supply, or maybe even the cell itself. However, it's far more practical to use a programmable battery charger. I bought a clone of a 'BMS6' from a well-known online RC model retailer, and I program it to think my battery pack uses LiLo rather than LiPo, which gives an end charge voltage of 4.1 V.

Comment: A potential gotcha is where the charger module sense the battery voltage relative to the charge energy source. If the sense terminal is separate there are various ways of making the sense amplifier see a higher voltage. If the charger senses Vbat at the charge output it can be harder. | If vsense is separate: Take a resistive divider from B+ to a higher voltage Vhi - say 5.1V. Tap the divider so that when B+ = 4.1 and Vhi = 5.1 then Vsense = 4.2 V. || You could also more elegantly) make a summing amplifier that adds 0.1V to Vbat and drives Vsense. ...

Comment: ...  || If Vbat and Vsense are inseparable you could provide a series MOSFET and sense amp with MOSFET driven so that 0.1V drop is maintained across it. Not hard - just annoying. As Neil says - a reprogrammable charger is the most elegant solution.

Comment: You know this is the third forum I have asked on and the only one to offer any sensible  solutions . Not one but three! Well done fellas.

Answer (score 1):

> *When charging a battery I want it to turn off before it charges to the
>   chargers full voltage.*

Well, that's one way but it's likely you haven't considered an alternative idea of limiting the voltage to 4.1 volts.

Build a precision voltage shunt circuit that limits the terminal voltage across the battery to 4.1 volts. In simple terms this is just a zener diode but, it probably needs to have better accuracy (possibly 1%) and a much sharper [knee voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode). In case you don't know what knee voltage is: -

[image]

Given that your terminal voltage appears to be that of a lithium cell, it's likely that at circa 4.1 volts the charging current will be fairly low and capable of being handled by the "zener circuit" without too much heat-sinking.

Comment: Well the battery can be anything .LFP LiPO etc. and charge current maybe of hundreds of amps but the idea is good for a relay control circuit that switches charge off at a zener set voltage ..thanks

Comment: Talk of zeners got me reminded of work I was doing a few months back on TL431 and how to cut overvoltage and of course this is the ideal for me . Adjustable as to what cut off point I want and a relay or mosfet to handle the needed current.
https://www.circuitspedia.com/over-voltage-protection-circuit/

Comment: How much current might the charger be producing at 4.1 volts?

Comment: It varies but 100 amps is possible for some 200 Ah LFP cells. at 3.5v required. Commonly  20-30 amps same voltage . Half an amp @ 4.1v for phone batteries ..Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually I got that wrong . The current on the top end of the charge will always be reduced to milliamps ,perhaps up to Amps for very large cells of say 300Ah. So Just 1 amp might be sufficient for smaller cells .

Comment: @April are we done here now or is there something you need clarifying?

Comment: Well you asked how much current and I answered wrongly . I still have not found a useable way to limit the charge on a charger that takes the cell to 4.2v down to 4.1v which is what I want to do? Either from inside the device or putting something outside but inline .

Comment: Use a precision zener diode (a precision shunt voltage regulator) and a series resistor to drop the 4.2 volts to 4.1 volts. That's a volt drop of 0.1 volts and if you need 1 amp that's a series resistance of 0.1 ohms. Obviously, the shunt regulator will dissipate 4.1 watts when the battery stops taking charge current but that's a different problem @April

Comment: Thanks Andy will try that .